# How to get reference to Angular built ControlGroup from within a Component?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a Component, containing a Template Driven form. What I really want to do is to add a code to `routerCanDeactivate` method to check if the form is `pristine` and if not, to warn the user before continuing with navigation. I know that Angular takes a Template Driven form and builds a ControlGroup. In the template, I can get to it like so: `<form #hf="ngForm" ...>` Is there a way to reference it from within a component?
If this is not possible, is there another way to check if the form is dirty from routeCanDeactivate?
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Where is the form? In the component that contains the link to the route?

Comment: The form is in the template of the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**preparing the form**

You need to add `ngControl` to each control

```
<input ngControl="someName" ...>
```

and `ngControlGroup` to each element between the inputs and the `<form>` element

```
<div ngControlGroup="groupName">
```

to get your form controls collected and managed by the `NgForm` directive.

**referencing the form**

If you only have one form in your template you can use

```
@ViewChild(NgForm) formA;
```

to get a reference to the form, otherwise add template variables to the forms

```
<form ngForm #formA="ngForm">
```

and get a reference using

```
@ViewChild('formA') formA;
```

then you can check `pristine` status like

```
routerCanDeactivate() {
  return this.form.pristine;
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/o1c2j9?p=preview)