# Property "touched" of ControlGroup not set correctly

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

My example form(ControlGroup) contains 2 Controls which are bound to 2 input fields. As a ControlGroup has a property "touched" I expect that this will be set to true when at least one of it's child controls has been "touched".
But this is not the case. The property "touched" of the ControlGroup is still set to false even though one of it's child Controls has been touched.
For the property "valid" instead this works as expected.
Am I wrong with my expectation?

I am using 2.0.0-beta.14

My example component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'form-group-example',
    template: `
        <h1>Angular 2 Control & Control Group example</h1>
        <form [ngFormModel]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <label for="firstname">Vorname</label>
            <input id="firstname" ngControl="firstname"/>
            <label for="lastname">Nachname</label>
            <input id="lastname" ngControl="lastname"/>

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    `
})
export class FormGroupExample {
    form: ControlGroup;

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = fb.group(
            {
                firstname: ['', Validators.maxLength(1)],
                lastname: [''],
            }
        );
    }

    onSubmit(): void {
        console.log("form touched", this.form.touched);
        console.log("form valid", this.form.valid);
    }
}
```

Comment: I experienced the same in the Plunker I added to http://stackoverflow.com/a/36591194/217408 `pristine` also works but `touched` doesn't. `touched` works on the control though https://plnkr.co/edit/mFlGI8?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere I read that touched is set at the onblur event. Maybe there is no unblur on the form.