# Angular 2 - get a reference to the formGroup

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms

In Angular 2 template driven forms, I can write

```
<form #form="ngForm">
[...]
</form>
```

ngForm is a FormGroup, as fare as I could understand. How do I grab that object in the corresponding component?

```
class FormComponent {
    formGroup: FormGroup;    // How do I have the form INJECTED AUTOMATICALLY by the framework? Something like a ViewChild, but it's not a view
}
```

It must be simple but the documentation only shows how to use the form in the template.

Thanks

EDIT: the type of what I want to grab is NgForm, not FormGroup!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access any template variable from the component using ViewChild decorator. In you case:

```
class FormComponent {
    @ViewChild('form') formGroup;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.formGroup.statusChanges().subscribe(() => {
            // Your code here!
        });
        console.log(this.formGroup); // Inspect the object for other available property and methods.
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried to do like u said but also used read: ViewContainerRef. That was wrong. Omitting the read option yields an NgForm, which is the actual type of the object I want, not FormGroup as I believed.
I understood this by looking at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583078/how-to-get-reference-to-angular-built-controlgroup-from-within-a-component?rq=1